# How to set same aspect ratio for subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to have a row of subplots with the same aspect ratio. Let's say I want to plot two different functions that have different extents on the y axis.

There seem to be lots of questions on this but the examples seem to conveniently have the same axes for all subplots. In any case none that I found were helpful to me.

I've tried the following

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdata = np.arange(0,2,.01)
ydata1 = xdata
ydata2 = xdata ** 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax[0].plot(xdata,ydata1)
ax[1].plot(xdata,ydata2)

ax[0].set_aspect(.5)
ax[1].set_aspect(.5)
plt.show(fig)
```

[image: plots]

However, matplotlib appears to be using the x and y axis data to determine the aspect ratio and because the y axes have different extents the subplots come out different. This is super weird to me. How do I make them the same physical aspect ratio?

I guess one can try extracting the the limits for each subplot and calculate the right aspect ratio individually but this seems to be a very roundabout way and I would expect such a basic functionality as making all subplots look the same to be built in.

EDIT So what I want is for both subplots to have the same aspect ratio in the human sense, that is that the ratio of the width of the figure to the height is the same for both. For example in Mathematica I would achieve this by simply setting the `AspectRatio` attribute:

```
xdata = Range[0, 2, .01];
ydata1 = {#, #} & /@ xdata;
ydata2 = {#, #^2} & /@ xdata;
fig = GraphicsRow[
   ListLinePlot[#, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Frame -> True, 
      ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {ydata1, ydata2}];
Export["fig.png", fig]
```

[image: Made by Mathematica]

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=True, sharey=True)`?

Comment: @Philo I think you're misinterpreting what setting the aspect ratio does in matplotlib.  you're also not very clear on how you want the figure to look, maybe you could draw a diagram? (ASCII art is fine)

Comment: @SamMason I've added a clarification to the question. soyapencil's answer seems to confirm my interpretation though.

Comment: at the moment the only control you have is to set the figure size and hope the resulting axes come out with an appropriate aspect ratio.  this is demonstrated by soyapencil and is what @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is referring to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** use the figsize keyword argument when making subplots:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdata = np.arange(0,2,.01)
ydata1 = xdata
ydata2 = xdata ** 2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
ax = fig.subplots(1,2)

ax[0].plot(xdata,ydata1)
ax[1].plot(xdata,ydata2)

# Squares
ax[0].plot([0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1])
ax[1].plot([0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1])

plt.show(fig)
```

`figsize` is a tuple in inches, with the first element as the width in the x-direction, the second element as the width in the y-direction.

It applies to the whole figure; you will need to tweak it to get a suitable shape for your subplots.

[image]

**Longer answer:** `.set_aspect(num)` sets the y-axis to x-axis ratio for each plot.

So, when you used `.set_aspect(.5)` on each axis, you told `matplotlib` to reconfigure each axis such that the y-axis is 0.5 times as big as the x-axis. This means that a 1x1 square actually looks like a rectangle on each plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdata = np.arange(0,2,.01)
ydata1 = xdata
ydata2 = xdata ** 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax[0].plot(xdata,ydata1)
ax[1].plot(xdata,ydata2)

# Squares
ax[0].plot([0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1])
ax[1].plot([0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1])

ax[0].set_aspect(.5)
ax[1].set_aspect(.5)
plt.show(fig)
```

That's why your plots are different shapes; the axis limits are *different*, but you've set the size of shapes on both plots to be *the same*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this comes closest to what I wanted. It still seems strange that you can't set a specific aspect ratio but I can work with this.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't entirely clear on what the desired outcome is. Possibly you want to have a fixed data aspect with out changing the axes?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdata = np.arange(0,2,.01)
ydata1 = xdata
ydata2 = xdata ** 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax[0].plot(xdata,ydata1)
ax[1].plot(xdata,ydata2)

ax[0].set_aspect(.5, adjustable="datalim")
ax[1].set_aspect(.5, adjustable="datalim")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want there to be needless empty space. I want the curves fill their entire plots and have the same physical aspect ratio. I've added a clarification to the question.

Comment: You misunderstood how matplotlib uses "aspect" then. Seems you just want to set the size of the subplots, without setting any aspect. That's what we will call "box aspect" in [some future version](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axes_box_aspect.html#shared-square-axes)